# How to check input data in YII2 for REST API?

Tags: yii2

How to check input data in YII2 for REST API?

Here's how it's done in a non-REST API:

**Controller**

```
<?php
namespace app\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\web\Controller;
use app\models\Index__GET;

class SiteController extends Controller
{
 
      public function actionIndex($ch_name_url = null)
      {
        $model = new Index__GET();
        $model->ch_name_url = $ch_name_url;

           if($model->validate()){ 
               return $this->render('index');
           }   

      }
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\base\Model;


class Index__GET extends Model
{

    public $ch_name_url;

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            ['ch_name_url', 'trim'],


            ['ch_name_url', 'required'],

        ];
    }
}
```

And now in the controller call `$model->validate()` for data validation. How to do validation incoming data in the REST API, using `yii\rest\Controller` and `yii\rest\ActiveController`?

I try but data validation fails:

I want a GET request to include two required fields.

But if I use `/users/123` I will receive data, while I should not receive it, because of the model `[['id', 'ch_name_url'], 'required'],`.

Me need `/users?id=123&ch_name_url=myname`

**Controller**

```
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class IndexController extends ActiveController
{
   public $modelClass = 'app\models\Index__GET';
}
```

**Model**

```
<?php
namespace app\models;

use Yii;
use yii\db\ActiveRecord;

class Index__GET extends ActiveRecord
{
    public $id;
    public $ch_name_url;
    public $email;
    
    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'user';
    }

    public function fields()
    {
        return ['id', 'ch_name_url', 'email'];
    }
    
    public function rules()
    {
        return [

            [['id', 'ch_name_url'], 'required'],
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: The default actionIndex and actionView of ActiveController do not call `$model->validate()`, so the rules are not used. For example, the code that runs in your example is [here](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rest/ViewAction.php), if you check it, you will see that it only calls checkAccess and, if true, returns the model. You need to implement your own method if you want to check against the rules.

Comment: @RaulSauco Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just create a controller extending from `\yii\rest\ActiveController`, then `validate` will run automatically. Do something like this:

```php
namespace app\controllers;

use yii\rest\ActiveController;

class IndexController extends ActiveController
{
   public $modelClass = 'app\models\Index__GET';
}
```

`$model->validate()` is called by default when you call `$model->save()`, but if you need to validate a model in an action, do it like you did on your question example code.

Just remember that the actions from REST are used a bit different from normal call, where `actionIndex` usually is not needed.

For more information, follow the original docs: [REST Quick Start](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-quick-start#creating-controller)

Comment: Thank you! I edit my question. Read please. I want a GET request to include two required fields.And the data is not validated if I use a GET request with parameters.

Comment: @TamaraSec Then you must update your `rules` and `tokens` take a look on this post [Adding parameters to Rest api](https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/adding-parameters-to-rest-api/78027/2) and follow this [official guide with examples](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/rest-routing).

Comment: But validation not working. I added rule in modele `['id', 'in', 'range' => [0, 5]],` and make GET request. `/api/v1/user/1` and I get data.

Comment: This kind of validation should no be done in the rules! Rules are to validate if a model is valid. What you want is to **filter** the possible results. Take a look at Yii2 filters.

Comment: What you want is to filter the possible results. ---> No. I want to validate data before making a query to the database.

Comment: The default actionIndex and actionView of ActiveController do not call $model->validate(), so the rules are not used.

Comment: So you have to override all the actions in that controller to implement validation before the query. But why are you worried about this kind of validation in a search? If is for security reasons, Yii2 automatically deal with data validation (not the model validation) before a database request.

Comment: I need this for security and performance. For example: I need to find data about a user by ten parameters. And I need to use JOIN (SQL) query for nine tables. But I only want to execute the query to database when it meet the necessary requirements.

Comment: Then override the action methods, or you could implement this validation in the `beforeFind` method of your model